# Created new project in Intellij Idea and gradle sync is failing again and again

Tags: android, firebase, intellij-idea

This is the error its showing even after BUILD SUCCESSFULL

08:14 pm    Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: AndroidArtifact.getBuildConfigFields().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3 s 678 ms)

And these are the implementations which i added and just connected it to Firebase

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'
```

Comment: This looks like some kind of version conflict. Maybe the Gradle version you use is too old?

Comment: How can i upgrade it??